# How to make a path that has two separate strokes with gaps inbetween?

Tags: inkscape

I am trying to make a simple repeatable texture (snake body for a simple snake game). I set up guides so that the tiles match, but I am having trouble making sure that both ends of the body segment lack stroke and match neatly.

This is my body with the first path segment removed on the left side:

[image]

Now if I use this button [image] to do the same on the right side, this happens:

[image]

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Your snake building block should be a group which contains three elements

- the green closed shape with no stroke
- the upped edge as an open shape with black stroke but no fill
- the lower edge as an open shape with black stroke but no fill

Not asked: Many vector drawing programs have more or less usefully implemented methods to force a horizontal piece to be bent and stretched to follow a path. Especially well it works in Illustrator where a shape or a group of shapes can be a brush.

In inkscape it's named "Pattern along Path" but I'm afraid it makes things difficult to be handled with code. In addition Inkscape's version do not accept multicolor groups, the bent and stretched shape must be a path or combined path which cannot have multiple colors. A workaround is to have several copies of the spine curve and everyone gets different pattern along.

Answer (score 0):

I would create this using a different method.

1. Create the first segment, in the same way you have already done.
2. Then duplicate the others, move and place them using snapping so you get an exact fit.
3. Edit the two end pieces, to create the head and tail of the snake.
4. Select all of them and do *Path > Union*
5. If you want the snake to bend, use a Pattern Along a Path effect.

[image]